# Editing a row in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I have a two text boxes named region id and region name..and a button control

I enter some values into those text boxes and click the button to insert those values into the "**gridview**"and a "**data table**" associated with the gridview.

The gridview has the "**enable editing**" set to true..but when i click the "**edit**" button of a particular row in a gridview i get no response...i.e i do not get editable textboxes as it happens normally...

What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the EditIndex of the row you are editting on the gdvMyGridView_RowEditing event:

```
gdvMyGridView.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
```

This will display your EditItemTemplate for the relevant row.

Answer (score 1):

[GridView Examples for ASP.NET 2.0: Editing the Underlying Data in a GridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx)

[Editable GridView in ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/Editable_GridView.aspx)

Comment: As i have mentioned in the question i have "enabled editing" and i am starting with an empty datagrid..the moment i enter some values in the two textboxes and click on the button one row gets added to the gridview and so on..and the gridview is bound to a datatable, not a "sql" or an "object data source"

Answer (score 0):

Edit control does not work out of blue. You have to write a backend SQL query for it to implement. The query will most likely look like this.

```
update regions SET name=@name where ID=@ID
```

where name and ID are fields of the table. *Make sure the ID is the primary key, otherwise update will not work and you won't get any error*.